# convertir complejos rectangulares a polares en c

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, estructuras

mi problema al ejecutar mi código es que la estructura declarada no la reconoce la función en la que la solicito.
estoy trabajando primeramente para sumar los compejos y devolverlos a forma polar, como lo describen las siguientes instrucciones:

```
/*/ *
    * QUE HACER:
    * Calcula la suma de los dos números complejos c1 y c2
    * Calcule los componentes resultantes en notación polar.
    * Devuelve el ComplexPolar resultante.
    *
    * Recuerde: suma de números complejos en notación cartesiana
    * está hecho por componentes
    * Recuerde: la magnitud de un número complejo se calcula como
    * mag = sqrt ((parte_real) ^ 2 + (parte_imaginaria) ^ 2)
    * y la fase de un número complejo se calcula como:
    * phi = atan2 (parte_imaginaria, parte_real)
    * /*/
```

Me podrían ayudar por favor? el siguiente es mi código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct complexCartesian
{
    float real;
    float img;
};

struct ComplexPolar
{
    float magnitude ;
    float angle;
};

struct ComplexPolar add_two_complex (struct ComplexCartesian c1, struct ComplexCartesian c2)
{

    
    
    
    struct complexCartesian c;

    c.real=c1.real += c2.real;
    c.img = c1.img += c2.img;
    return(c);


    struct ComplexPolar result;

    result.magnitude = sqrt(pow(c1,2)+pow(c2,2));
     result.angle = atan(c1/c2)*180/3.1416;

  }





int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    struct ComplexCartesian c1, c2;
    struct  ComplexPolar result;
    
    if (argc> 4)
    {
        c1.real = atof (argv [1]);
        c1.img = atof (argv [2]);
        c2.real = atof (argv [3]);
        c2.img = atof (argv [4]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Ingrese la parte real del primer número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c1.real);
        printf ("Ingresa la parte imaginaria del primer número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c1.img);
        printf ("Ingrese la parte real del segundo número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c2.real);
        printf ("Ingresa la parte imaginaria del segundo número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c2.img);
        printf ("El complejo resultante en notación polar es: \n");
    }

    result = add_two_complex (c1, c2);
    printf ("% 0.7f ang% 0.7f \n", result.magnitude, result.angle);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fíjate que has incluído un return en mitad de la función:

```
struct complexCartesian c;

c.real=c1.real += c2.real;
c.img = c1.img += c2.img;
return(c); // <<--- AQUI
```

Ese `return` devuelve un objeto de tipo `complexCartesian`, y la función espera que el valor de retorno sea de tipo `complexPolar`... ahí tienes el error. Ese `return` sobra.

Pero la cosa no acaba aquí el código que sigue al `return` tampoco es válido:

```
result.magnitude = sqrt(pow(c1,2)+pow(c2,2));
```

`c1` y `c2` son estructuras, no floats o enteros. El compilador no sabe cómo convertir una estructura a un entero y, de saber, seguramente no te iba a gustar el resultado porque no lo has programado en ningún sitio... ya sería casualidad que la función hiciese (repito, si funcionase, que no lo va a hacer por fortuna para ti) lo que tu esperas así por azar.

Lo que tienes que hacer en estas líneas es indicar qué elemento de la estructura quieres recuperar en cada momento. Nota también que aquí deberías usar `c`, que es la estructura que almacena la suma de los dos números complejos:

```
result.magnitude = sqrt(pow(c.real,2)+pow(c.img,2));
result.angle = // ...
```

Comment: ok, ahora entiendo como utilizar la estructura, pero al verific ar me sigue dando este error:

Comment: struct complexCartesian" no tiene un miembro llamado "angle"
     c. ángulo = atan (c1 / c2) * 180 / 3,1416;
      ^
Assignment06.c: 60: 22: error: operandos no válidos para binary / (tienen "struct complexCartesian" y "struct complexCartesian")
     c. ángulo = atan (c1 / c2) * 180 / 3,1416;
                      ^
Asignación06.c: En función "principal":
Assignment06.c: 70: 29: error: no se conoce el tamaño de almacenamiento de "c1"
     struct ComplexCartesian c1, c2;
                             ^ ~

Comment: comprendo que el primer error es marcado porque se utiliza el valor de c que está declarada solo para struct cartesianos xD,

Comment: hola, @eferion creo que en el error que dice binario, es por que no recoce la opreación?

Answer (score 1):

ya encontré otros errores, consistían básicamente el la sintaxis, ya que había mayúsculas en otras áreas, es decir:

```
`#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

struct complexCartesian
{
    float real;
    float img;
};

struct ComplexPolar
{
    float magnitude ;
    float angle;
};

struct ComplexPolar add_two_complex (struct complexCartesian c1, struct complexCartesian c2)
{

   // auxcomplex x = 
    /*/ *
     * QUE HACER:
     * Calcula la suma de los dos números complejos c1 y c2
     * Calcule los componentes resultantes en notación polar.
     * Devuelve el ComplexPolar resultante.
     *
     * Recuerde: suma de números complejos en notación cartesiana
     * está hecho por componentes
     * Recuerde: la magnitud de un número complejo se calcula como
     * mag = sqrt ((parte_real) ^ 2 + (parte_imaginaria) ^ 2)
     * y la fase de un número complejo se calcula como:
     * phi = atan2 (parte_imaginaria, parte_real)
     * /*/
    
    
    struct complexCartesian c;

    c.real=c1.real += c2.real;
    c.img = c1.img += c2.img;
    


    struct ComplexPolar result;
    

    result.magnitude = sqrt(pow(c.real,2)+pow(c.img,2));
    result.angle = atan2(c1,c2)*180/3.1416;



  }





int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    struct complexCartesian c1, c2;
    struct  ComplexPolar result;
    
    if (argc> 4)
    {
        c1.real = atof (argv [1]);
        c1.img = atof (argv [2]);
        c2.real = atof (argv [3]);
        c2.img = atof (argv [4]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("Ingrese la parte real del primer número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c1.real);
        printf ("Ingresa la parte imaginaria del primer número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c1.img);
        printf ("Ingrese la parte real del segundo número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c2.real);
        printf ("Ingresa la parte imaginaria del segundo número:");
        scanf ("% f", & c2.img);
        printf ("El complejo resultante en notación polar es: \n");
    }

    result = add_two_complex (c1, c2);
    printf ("% 0.7f ang% 0.7f \n", result.magnitude, result.angle);
    return 0;
}`
```

> struct ComplexCartesian c1, c2;

vs la correcta:

> struct complexCartesian c1, c2;

Observar las mayúsculas y minúsculas,por esta razón no se reconocía el tamaño de c1 y c2.
una disculpa xD.

si encuentran otro error ayúdenme.

muchas gracias @eferion